# Who first started to name 'blockchain technology' as 'blockchain'

Tags: blockchain, terminology, history

I read through the whitepaper of Satoshi Nakamoto.

I could find the expression 'blocks are chained...' but he did not specifically use the word 'blockchain' itself.

I want to know the origin of the term blockchain....

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The first use of the phrase "block chain" was by Hal Finney in his [response](https://satoshi.nakamotoinstitute.org/emails/cryptography/threads/1/#014827) to Satoshi's email with the whitepaper. Over time, the two words have been combined into the single word "blockchain".

Comment: thank you veryyy much professor